# XAML binding using Reflected property data

Tags: silverlight, xaml, reflection, binding

I have a simple class,  ClassA (below).  Is it somehow possible that in my XAML repeater I can bind the reflected property names to a textbox and be able to bind a checkbox IsChecked to the bool property?  So my XAML might be something like (this is just pseudo-xaml, not sure if it is syntactically correct, and assume ItemsControl data context is ClassA):

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ??? reflected property name as text, e.g., ClassABool1 ??? }"
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ??? somehow bind to the actual property ClassABool1 ???, Mode=TwoWay}"
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>


public sealed class ClassA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler  PropertyChanged;
    private static ClassA _instance;
    private ClassA() {}

    public static ClassA Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new ClassA();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private bool _classABool1;
    public bool ClassABool1 { get; set; }

    private bool _classABool2;
    public bool ClassABool2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work almost exactly as you describe.

When you create a Binding (in XAML or in code), you define your target property using a string to describe the path relative to the data context.

In the following example, if you assign an instance of ClassA to the `Content property` of the ContentControl, the `Data Context` of your Bindings will be that instance.

```
<ContentControl Content="An Instance of ClassA">
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClassABool1}" />

                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ClassABool1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

[More on Data Binding here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc278072%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I understand data binding, but what I'm after: Is it possible to set the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl to the property collection of ClassA.  Then the textbox would bind to the property name.  The checkbox I would then like to bind to the property value.

So in the original example, assuming it ran, would generate 2 data items since ClassA has 2 properties, the first data item would be the text of 'ClassABool1' followed by a checkbox whose IsChecked property is bound to ClassABool1's value.  The second data item would be a duplicate of the first, but with ClassABool2.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you want to bind your ItemsControl ItemsSource to an instance of ClassA and then display item per property?

Comment: No, the ItemsControl source would be the property collection of ClassA, the TextBox Text would bind to Property.Name, and the CheckBox IsChecked would somehow bind to the actual property.  So given ClassA above with it's 2 properties, my ItemsControl would produce 2 "rows":  1st "row":  ClassABool1 as text for first textbox, followed by a checkbox whose IsChecked is bound to ClassABool1.  2nd "row":  same thing, but with ClassABool2 property.   Ultimately it shouldn't matter how many properties ClassA has, if ClassA had 20 properties, then the process would repeat for items 3-20. Thanks again!